# Align ImageView to Left or Right of LinearLayout on Runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a `LinearLayout` and `ImageView`, when user receives a message the `ImageView` should be on the right and `LinearLayout` on it's left, and when sends a message, the `ImageView` should be on the left and the `LinearLayout` on it's right.
how can i do this on runtime?

here is my xml

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageViewDelivered"
           android:layout_width="15sp"
           android:layout_height="15sp"
           android:src="@drawable/success"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"
           android:layout_marginRight="4sp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
           android:contentDescription="@string/emptytext" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/incoming_message_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:maxWidth="250dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

thanks.

Comment: It may be simpler if you defined 2 separate layouts for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the root layout(which is parent of your `LinearLayout` and `ImageView`) to `RelativeLayout`  in your xml file.

Initialize both views:

```
LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contentWithBackground);
ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewDelivered);
```

Initialize the `LayoutParam` of `LinearLayout` and `ImageView`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams linearLp=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)linear.getLayoutParams();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageLp=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams();
```

To set the `LinearLayout` to left of `ImageView` :

```
linearLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,image.getId());
```

To set the `LinearLayout` to right of `ImageView` :

```
linearLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,image.getId());
```

Comment: i tried your code, now the imageview is fixed on the Left side, and the linearlayout is either above it (second case), or in the right side of the screen (first case)

Comment: Well as you can see, I haven't created any new `LayoutParam`, whatever your `LinearLayout` have I just added one more property. You need to change accordingly in your xml file to meet your need.